# Working with lists in .csv columns in Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm doing a project that involves a mini-database in a .csv file. I have the `csv` module.
The file has four columns:

```
word_number;sentence;pronoun;variants
```

And I need to be able to write to it a list of lists (where each one contains a row), and later, if needed, get this list of lists back.
The problem is, the second and the fourth columns also have to contain lists... And they turn into strings because of quoting. I tried to use sets of parameters like these for both reader and writer:

```
(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter=";", escapechar=' ',)
(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter=';', quotechar='',escapechar='\\')
```

And none of them help.
Strings in lists in those two columns may contain commas and apostrophes, so I'm trying to override that too.

Sorry if that's a stupid question, but I just don't get what `QUOTE_NONE` is supposed to do anymore and it all just starts to make no sense to me.

An example of list of lists:

```
[[1, ['У', 'мене', 'не', '(', 'є', ')', 'велика', "сім'я", '.'], 'мене', ['я', 'мені']], 
[0, ['Моя', "сім'я", '—', 'це', 'я', ',', 'мама', 'і', 'тато', '.'], 'Моя', ['Моєї', 'Моїй', 'Мою']], 
[3, ['Моя', "сім'я", '—', 'це', 'я', ',', 'мама', 'і', 'тато', '.'], 'це', ['цього', 'цьому', 'цім']], 
[4, ['Моя', "сім'я", '—', 'це', 'я', ',', 'мама', 'і', 'тато', '.'], 'я', ['мене', 'мені']], 
[0, ['Мого', 'тата', 'звати', 'Іван', '.'], 'Мого', ['Мій', 'Моєму']]]
```

It goes like this in the .csv file:

```
1;['У',  'мене',  'не',  '(',  'є',  ')',  'велика',   "сім'я ",  '.'];мене;['я',  'мені']
0;['Моя',   "сім'я ",  '—',  'це',  'я',  ',',  'мама',  'і',  'тато',  '.'];Моя;['Моєї',  'Моїй',  'Мою']
3;['Моя',   "сім'я ",  '—',  'це',  'я',  ',',  'мама',  'і',  'тато',  '.'];це;['цього',  'цьому',  'цім']
4;['Моя',   "сім'я ",  '—',  'це',  'я',  ',',  'мама',  'і',  'тато',  '.'];я;['мене',  'мені']
0;['Мого',  'тата',  'звати',  'Іван',  '.'];Мого;['Мій',  'Моєму']
```

And it reads from the file into this:

```
['1', '[\'У\', \'мене\', \'не\', \'(\', \'є\', \')\', \'велика\', "сім\'я", \'.\']', 'мене', "['я', 'мені']"]
['0', '[\'Моя\', "сім\'я", \'—\', \'це\', \'я\', \',\', \'мама\', \'і\', \'тато\', \'.\']', 'Моя', "['Моєї', 'Моїй', 'Мою']"]
['3', '[\'Моя\', "сім\'я", \'—\', \'це\', \'я\', \',\', \'мама\', \'і\', \'тато\', \'.\']', 'це', "['цього', 'цьому', 'цім']"]
['4', '[\'Моя\', "сім\'я", \'—\', \'це\', \'я\', \',\', \'мама\', \'і\', \'тато\', \'.\']', 'я', "['мене', 'мені']"]
['0', "['Мого', 'тата', 'звати', 'Іван', '.']", 'Мого', "['Мій', 'Моєму']"]
```

It's a cyrillic language, so I'm sorry if that's problematic to read. I guess I could do examples with latin alphabet if needed.

I'm thinking of maybe just transforming those lists-turned-into-strings back into lists somehow? But I'm really not sure how to do that at all. Strip each one of [], then split by the combinations of quotes, spaces and commas using re.split? Guess it could work like that, but I'm sure it'd be much easier and nicer to solve this problem with .csv.

I'd be beyond thankful for any help!

Comment: Would you be open to use libraries? E.g. Pandas? It would reduce the complexity of the solution.

Comment: @Andreas yes, definitely!

Comment: You want to turn string of list back to list, right ?

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer basically, yes. My list gets quoted and turns into a string, so I need to either stop it from doing that or find a way to reverse this process later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert string of list back to list you can do this:

```
import ast
a = "['я', 'мені']"
a = ast.literal_eval(a)
print(a,type(a))
```

Output:

```
['я', 'мені'] <class 'list'>
```

You can see the documentation for this function here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: sorry that it takes so long for me to answer, I have to change other problems in my code to check if this works, but I checked outside the project and it seems to me it does! will mark as a solution later when I know for sure, but thanks already!

Comment: @lithium Yes sure, let me know, Glad to help you.