# Different format of read rows in .csv stops from checking if the new ones are the same

Tags: python, csv

I'm doing a project where I need to write and read a `.csv` file.
It's in a cyrillic language that also uses apostrophes and data in the file may also have commas, so there are some issues when reading it.

Basically, the file is written from a list of lists. Two of the columns also have lists for values.
You could read more about that issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67399942/working-with-lists-in-csv-columns-in-python).

An example of list of lists:

```
[[1, ['У', 'мене', 'не', '(', 'є', ')', 'велика', "сім'я", '.'], 'мене', ['я', 'мені']], 
[0, ['Моя', "сім'я", '—', 'це', 'я', ',', 'мама', 'і', 'тато', '.'], 'Моя', ['Моєї', 'Моїй', 'Мою']], 
[3, ['Моя', "сім'я", '—', 'це', 'я', ',', 'мама', 'і', 'тато', '.'], 'це', ['цього', 'цьому', 'цім']], 
[4, ['Моя', "сім'я", '—', 'це', 'я', ',', 'мама', 'і', 'тато', '.'], 'я', ['мене', 'мені']], 
[0, ['Мого', 'тата', 'звати', 'Іван', '.'], 'Мого', ['Мій', 'Моєму']]]
```

It goes like this in the .csv file:

```
1;['У',  'мене',  'не',  '(',  'є',  ')',  'велика',   "сім'я ",  '.'];мене;['я',  'мені']
0;['Моя',   "сім'я ",  '—',  'це',  'я',  ',',  'мама',  'і',  'тато',  '.'];Моя;['Моєї',  'Моїй',  'Мою']
3;['Моя',   "сім'я ",  '—',  'це',  'я',  ',',  'мама',  'і',  'тато',  '.'];це;['цього',  'цьому',  'цім']
4;['Моя',   "сім'я ",  '—',  'це',  'я',  ',',  'мама',  'і',  'тато',  '.'];я;['мене',  'мені']
0;['Мого',  'тата',  'звати',  'Іван',  '.'];Мого;['Мій',  'Моєму']
```

And it reads from the file into this:

```
['1', '[\'У\', \'мене\', \'не\', \'(\', \'є\', \')\', \'велика\', "сім\'я", \'.\']', 'мене', "['я', 'мені']"]
['0', '[\'Моя\', "сім\'я", \'—\', \'це\', \'я\', \',\', \'мама\', \'і\', \'тато\', \'.\']', 'Моя', "['Моєї', 'Моїй', 'Мою']"]
['3', '[\'Моя\', "сім\'я", \'—\', \'це\', \'я\', \',\', \'мама\', \'і\', \'тато\', \'.\']', 'це', "['цього', 'цьому', 'цім']"]
['4', '[\'Моя\', "сім\'я", \'—\', \'це\', \'я\', \',\', \'мама\', \'і\', \'тато\', \'.\']', 'я', "['мене', 'мені']"]
['0', "['Мого', 'тата', 'звати', 'Іван', '.']", 'Мого', "['Мій', 'Моєму']"]
```

So, let's imagine our file already has those rows, but the user tries to write them again. I try to prevent that:

```
for row in csvreader:
    rows.append(row)

for i in new_list:
    if i in rows or i == []:
        continue
    else:
        csvwriter.writerow(i)
```

But it doesn't work, cause the list that goes in and the list that reads from the file are actually different (as you can see in the 1st and the 3rd examples), so they don't compare.

I could, of course, just write the rows into the file first, then read them again and delete any duplicates, but I feel that wouldn't be good.

So maybe there is another way of doing it?
I'd be beyond thankful for any help!

*Also, at this point it'd be good if I didn't have to use pandas, because I struggled with this part of the code enough to not want to change much if at all possible. But if not, I'll accept pandas, that's okay. I'll look into it later, if there are no other ways.*

The last question about it got closed, but the answer it got associated with didn't resolve it, unfortunately, and didn't apply at all -- checked on similar data:

```
array1 = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7]
array2 = [1, 5, 2, 4, 8, 7]

for i in array2:
    if i in array1:
        continue
    else:
        array1.append(i)

print(array1)  # output: [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission.

Given the way your program works and since you're just ignoring duplicates with `continue`, let the user write duplicates anyway then sanitize it by removing duplicates with pandas' `df.drop_duplicates()`.

Comment: thanks! didn't do that first, but that's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I used `pandas`. It is much easier for both my previous question and this one -- just because it lets you work with dataframes and configure data types for each column (including using `ast` to have lists in `.csv` columns) etc.

Had to waste a lot of time, but I think it was worth it. If you have any questions of the same kind, feel free to comment here and I'll try to help!